# Why don't similiar keyChar and keyCode equal in KeyStroke?

Tags: java, swing

I don't understand why this gives false and is not regarded as equal.

```
KeyStroke test1 = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('1');
KeyStroke test2 = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_1, 0);
System.out.println(test1.equals(test2));
```

In which situation shall this not be equal, i.e. is this a feature or a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're passing in the first line is a `Character` and `KeyEvent.VK_1` is an `Integer` represented in Hex (0x30).
The numbers and keys are represented by the primitive type `int` with hex values.

E.g.: Numbers from 0 to 9 are hexa represented this way:

```
public static final int VK_0              = 0x30;
...
public static final int VK_9              = 0x39;
```

### Edit

They're being different because the first KeyStroke considers that the number 1 was typed
The second KeyStroke is considering a pressed 1.

They're not different keys, but different actions

```
    KeyStroke test1 = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('1', KeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_UNKNOWN);
    KeyStroke test2 = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_1, KeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_UNKNOWN);

    System.out.println(test1.equals(test2));
```

This will be `true`

That 0 parameter `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_1, 0);`
represents the constant `KeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_UNKNOWN`

The documentation says:

```
  A constant indicating that the keyLocation is indeterminate
  or not relevant.
  KEY_TYPED events do not have a keyLocation; this value
  is used instead.
```

Comment: I know that, but KeyStroke shall encode a key stroke, right? Now what's the difference from a "key stroke" point of view between test1 and test2? Ain't that the same key stroke? I would argue yes, as `System.out.println("char " + (char) KeyEvent.VK_1);` implies this too.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I start to get it. Although I still don't really understand the difference between press and type. Can type occur only in text fields? After reading http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html I got it.

Comment: For example, pressing the Shift key will cause a KEY_PRESSED event with a VK_SHIFT keyCode, while pressing the 'a' key will result in a VK_A keyCode. After the 'a' key is released, a KEY_RELEASED event will be fired with VK_A. Separately, a KEY_TYPED event with a keyChar value of 'A' is generated.

Comment: Type can occurs in every component that has a place to write (JComboBox, A cell of a JTable, etc).

I'm glad I could help! =D